# Swift4 initWithArray equivalent

Tags: arrays, swift, nsmutablearray

New to Swift. Is there an Swift equivalent function for `initWithArray` on a `NSMutableArray` in Objective-C?

I have the following code in Obj-C

```
 tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:dataArray];
```

And i am trying to use the following in Swift

```
var tempArray = [[[String:String]]]()
var dataArray: [[String: String]]
tempArray.append(dataArray)
```

The problem is the count for the tempArray comes as 1 (which logically seems right). All i want to do is add the dataArray which is an array holding dictionary objects to the tempArray. I want to use native Swift array if possible.

EDIT:
After making the changes as suggested, i am getting the following error:

```
Cannot convert value of type [[String:String]] to expected argument type[String:String]

var tempArray = [[String:String]]()

    var dataArray: [[String: String]] =

        [["name": "John", "Address": "XYZ"],
         ["name": "Doe",  "Address": "ABC"]]

tempArray.append(dataArray)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think you are looking for is `append(contentsOf:)`. You are also using a dictionary type (`String:String`) rather than an array type. Try the following:

```
var tempArray = [String]()
let dataArray: [String] = ["An", "array", "of", "String"] // just an example
tempArray.append(contentsOf: dataArray)
```

Closer to your Objective-C might be:

```
let dataArray: [String] = ["An", "array", "of", "String"]
var tempArray = [String](dataArray)
```

You can find these methods (the second is one of the `init` methods) on the `Array` documentation page in Xcode.

**Addendum**

As per comment you have an array of dictionary, just change the element type from `String` to `[String:String]`, all the methods used are generic (independent of element type). In the example I must change by literal test data as well:

```
var tempArray = [[String:String]]()
let dataArray: [[String:String]] = [["a" : "A", "b" : "dict"], ["a" : "another", "b" : "dict"]]
tempArray.append(contentsOf: dataArray)
```

HTH

Comment: I need to use a dictionary type because my dataArray actually is an array holding dictionary objects. How do i go about using it?

Comment: OK, in that case you need to replace `String` with your dictionary type, maybe `[String:String]`? And of course my sample data will be wrong in that case! The structure of the above code remains exactly the same, the methods (`append`,`init`) are generic and work on arrays of any element type.

Comment: If i try that then i am not able to append the entire tempArray to the dataArray. 
var tempArray = [[String:String]]()
I get a cannot convert value of type [[String:String]] to [String:String]

Comment: @user2511882 - See addendum, you just need to change the type to whatever you require.

Comment: Please check the updated question. Still having the same issue. Apologies about the confusion here.

Comment: Re-read the answer carefully, it does exactly what you want without error.

Comment: Err it worked now for some reason. Though i didn't change anything. Will accept the answer. Thanks.